# Checking node and it's all childrens on the basis of id

Tags: d3.js

I am working on angular application which uses d3

```
const treeData = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Root",
  "checked": false,
  "color": "white",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
        "name": "Leaf A",
      "checked": false,
      "color": "red",
        "children": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "A - 1",
                "checked": false,
          "color": "brown",
          }, 
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "A - 2",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "orange",
          },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "A - 3",
                "checked": false,
          "color": "yellow",
          },
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "id": 6,
        "name": "Leaf B",
      "checked": false,
      "color": "green",
        "children": [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "B - 1",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "#00ff40",
          }, 
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "B - 2",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "#00ff80",
          }
      ]
    }
  ]  
};

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

Fiddle is as follows

I am working on d3.js. My code is as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/g543kxoh/

From a API I will be getting a id. This id will match id of any node present in above data. I need to make that node checked and all its childrens and subchildrens checked too. How I can do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question right.. You need to write a function that finds a node by ID and check it and all of its descendants?

Comment: yes. That's what I needed. We will provide a id, that will be unique id for a node and check it and all its descendants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function `selectNode` to find node by ID, expand it and its ancestors, and check it (and its descendants).

```js
const selectNode = id => {
   const node = findNode(treeData, id);
   if (node) {
      for (let index = node.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        expand(node[index]);
      }
      checkNode(node[0], true, false);
      update(root);
   }
};
```

See a demo in the fiddle. One node is selected after 2 seconds, then another node is selected as well:

```js
const treeData = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Root",
  "checked": false,
  "color": "white",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Leaf A",
      "checked": false,
      "color": "red",
        "children": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "A - 1",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "brown",
          }, 
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "A - 2",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "orange",
          },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "A - 3",
                "checked": false,
          "color": "yellow",
          },
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "id": 6,
        "name": "Leaf B",
      "checked": false,
      "color": "green",
        "children": [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "B - 1",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "#00ff40",
          }, 
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "B - 2",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "#00ff80",
          }
      ]
    }
  ]  
};

const margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  };
  
const width = 600 - margin.right - margin.left;
const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,duration = 750;
  
const tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

const diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });


const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
  
const container = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const root = treeData;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function expand(d) {
  if (d._children) {
    d.children = d._children
    d._children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {
  // Compute the new tree layout.
  const nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
  const links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 200;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  const node = container.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, d => d.id);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.y0},${source.x0})`)
    .on("click", onClickNode);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", d => d.color);

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("dy", 4)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(d => d.name);
    
  nodeEnter.append('foreignObject')
    .attr('width', '20')
    .attr('height', '20')
    .attr("x", -30)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .append('xhtml:input')
    .attr('type', 'checkbox')
    .attr("id", d => `checkbox-${d.id}`)
    .on("click", onClickCheckbox)

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  // ???
  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .style("stroke", 'black');
  nodeUpdate.each(function(d) {
    const cb = d3.select(this).select('[type="checkbox"]').node();
    cb.checked = d.checked;
    cb.disabled = isParentChecked(d);
  });
    
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  const nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 0);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0);

  // Update the links…
  var link = container.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, d => d.target.id);

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .attr("opacity", "0.3")
    .style("stroke", 'black');

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

function findParent(datum) {
  if (datum.depth < 2) {
    return datum.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.parent)
  }
}

function findParentLinks(datum) {
  if (datum.target.depth < 2) {
    return datum.target.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.target.parent)
  }
}

const checkNode = (d, checked, byParent) => {
  d.checked = checked;
  const children = d.children || d._children;
  if (children)
    children.forEach(child => checkNode(child, checked, true));
    
  if (!byParent && checked && d.parent) {
    const siblings = d.parent.children || d.parent._children;
    
    siblings.forEach(sibling => {
      if (sibling.id !== d.id) {
        console.log('UNCHECK: ', sibling)
        checkNode(sibling, false, true);
      }
    });
    
  }  
  
}

function isParentChecked (d) {
  if (!d.parent) {
    return false;
  }
  if (d.parent.checked) {
    return true;
  }
  return isParentChecked(d.parent);
}

function onClickCheckbox(d) {
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
  checkNode(d, d3.event.target.checked, false);
  console.log('ROOT: ', root);
  update(root);   
}


// Toggle children on click.
function onClickNode(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } 
  else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

const findNode = (parent, id) => {
  if (parent.id === id)
    return [parent];
    
  const children = parent.children || parent._children;
  if (children) {
        for (let child of children) {
        const found = findNode(child, id);
        if (found)
          return [...found, parent];
      }
  }
  return null;
}

const selectNode = id => {
   const node = findNode(treeData, id);
   if (node) {
      for (let index = node.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        expand(node[index]);
      }
      checkNode(node[0], true, false);
      update(root);
   }
};

setTimeout(() => selectNode(2), 2000);
setTimeout(() => selectNode(6), 4000);
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will test it and will let you know :). Could you please mark comments on the code which you added, it will be helpful for me to understand it. and just one question. In this case if B-1 node or B-2 node has childs will they will be also checked?

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks. It is working fine for me. I will upvote and accept this answer. Thanks a lot :) One more thing, Could you please tell me some good resources to learn and get command over d3.js

Comment: D3 formal documentation is a tough one, so the best way is to learn the code examples. The problem with the D3 examples is that most of them are outdated (written for V3/V4/V5) and not usable for V6 (the latest). So when you look for an example, make sure it uses V6. I also suggest to learn SVG basics with the tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp

Comment: Hi Michael, just a question in this code. If id is passed and if I also want to check parents and superparents, then how we can do that?

Comment: You can perform a recursive search from root and check all the ancestors until the node itself. Here is an example (see findNodeAncestors function): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549992/programmatically-open-nested-collapsed-hidden-nodes-in-d3-js-v6

Comment: but if this code will check all the ancestor until given node so just want to know will it check siblings too? I don't want to check siblings to be checked and where I need to call this findNodeAncestor in your code. Means how to integrate with the code which you gave above

Comment: @Julie can you please post another question with your current snippet and explanation of the problem and I will try to answer it tomorrow with a working example

Comment: ok I am posting two questions and will share link here. Please have a look at it

Comment: Hi, I have posted a separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749747/checking-parents-with-childrens-of-a-node please have a look