# Checking parents with children of a node

Tags: d3.js

I am working on angular application with d3.js. My code is as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/8hw1brq0/

```
const treeData = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Root",
  "checked": false,
  "color": "white",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Leaf A",
      "checked": false,
      "color": "red",
        "children": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "A - 1",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "brown",
          }, 
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "A - 2",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "orange",
          },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "A - 3",
                "checked": false,
          "color": "yellow",
          },
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "id": 6,
        "name": "Leaf B",
      "checked": false,
      "color": "green",
        "children": [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "B - 1",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "#00ff40",
          }, 
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "B - 2",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "#00ff80",
          }
      ]
    }
  ]  
};

const margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  };
  
const width = 600 - margin.right - margin.left;
const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,duration = 750;
  
const tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

const diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });


const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
  
const container = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const root = treeData;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function expand(d) {
  if (d._children) {
    d.children = d._children
    d._children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {
  // Compute the new tree layout.
  const nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
  const links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 200;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  const node = container.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, d => d.id);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.y0},${source.x0})`)
    .on("click", onClickNode);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", d => d.color);

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("dy", 4)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(d => d.name);
    
  nodeEnter.append('foreignObject')
    .attr('width', '20')
    .attr('height', '20')
    .attr("x", -30)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .append('xhtml:input')
    .attr('type', 'checkbox')
    .attr("id", d => `checkbox-${d.id}`)
    .on("click", onClickCheckbox)

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  // ???
  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .style("stroke", 'black');
  nodeUpdate.each(function(d) {
    const cb = d3.select(this).select('[type="checkbox"]').node();
    cb.checked = d.checked;
    cb.disabled = isParentChecked(d);
  });
    
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  const nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 0);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0);

  // Update the links…
  var link = container.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, d => d.target.id);

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .attr("opacity", "0.3")
    .style("stroke", 'black');

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

function findParent(datum) {
  if (datum.depth < 2) {
    return datum.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.parent)
  }
}

function findParentLinks(datum) {
  if (datum.target.depth < 2) {
    return datum.target.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.target.parent)
  }
}

const checkNode = (d, checked, byParent) => {
  d.checked = checked;
  const children = d.children || d._children;
  if (children)
    children.forEach(child => checkNode(child, checked, true));
    
  if (!byParent && checked && d.parent) {
    const siblings = d.parent.children || d.parent._children;
    
    siblings.forEach(sibling => {
      if (sibling.id !== d.id) {
        console.log('UNCHECK: ', sibling)
        checkNode(sibling, false, true);
      }
    });
    
  }  
  
}

function isParentChecked (d) {
  if (!d.parent) {
    return false;
  }
  if (d.parent.checked) {
    return true;
  }
  return isParentChecked(d.parent);
}

function onClickCheckbox(d) {
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
  checkNode(d, d3.event.target.checked, false);
  console.log('ROOT: ', root);
  update(root);   
}


// Toggle children on click.
function onClickNode(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } 
  else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

const findNode = (parent, id) => {
  if (parent.id === id)
    return [parent];
    
  const children = parent.children || parent._children;
  if (children) {
        for (let child of children) {
        const found = findNode(child, id);
        if (found)
          return [...found, parent];
      }
  }
  return null;
}

const selectNode = id => {
   const node = findNode(treeData, id);
   if (node) {
      for (let index = node.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        expand(node[index]);
      }
      checkNode(node[0], true, false);
      update(root);
   }
};

setTimeout(() => selectNode(2), 2000);
setTimeout(() => selectNode(6), 4000);
```

In this if a checkbox is checked then all it's children are also checked. With children I want to check all parent's and superparent's too. How can I do that?

Comment: Let me understand. If a parent node has 2 children (both unchecked) and the user checks one of them, the checked node and all of its descendants should be checked. If one of the nodes already checked and the user checks another node, we should check the parent as well? Is it correct?

Comment: I ask a question, because previously when we checked a node that have an already checked sibling, we would uncheck that sibling because only one child is allowed to be cheked. So the new requirement contradicts the prevoious

Comment: This sibling condition is not in picture now for me.  so if node is checked then I want all the children's to be checked which we are doing in the code you provided. In this with children I need to check parent's as well.

Comment: Hi Michael I replied to your question. let me know in case if any info needed from my end

Comment: Hi Michael, you providing answer to this today? I will also be posting another question in sometime

Answer (score -1):

Inclusive selection logic implemented:

```js
const treeData = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Root",
  "checked": false,
  "color": "white",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Leaf A",
      "checked": false,
      "color": "red",
        "children": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "A - 1",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "brown",
          }, 
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "A - 2",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "orange",
          },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "A - 3",
                "checked": false,
          "color": "yellow",
          },
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "id": 6,
        "name": "Leaf B",
      "checked": false,
      "color": "green",
        "children": [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "B - 1",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "#00ff40",
          }, 
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "B - 2",
          "checked": false,
          "color": "#00ff80",
          }
      ]
    }
  ]  
};

const margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  };
  
const width = 600 - margin.right - margin.left;
const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,duration = 750;
  
const tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

const diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });


const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
  
const container = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const root = treeData;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function expand(d) {
  if (d._children) {
    d.children = d._children
    d._children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {
  // Compute the new tree layout.
  const nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
  const links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 200;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  const node = container.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, d => d.id);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.y0},${source.x0})`)
    .on("click", onClickNode);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", d => d.color);

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("dy", 4)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(d => d.name);
    
  nodeEnter.append('foreignObject')
    .attr('width', '20')
    .attr('height', '20')
    .attr("x", -30)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .append('xhtml:input')
    .attr('type', 'checkbox')
    .attr("id", d => `checkbox-${d.id}`)
    .on("click", onClickCheckbox)

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  // ???
  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .style("stroke", 'black');
  nodeUpdate.each(function(d) {
    const cb = d3.select(this).select('[type="checkbox"]').node();
    cb.checked = d.checked;
    cb.disabled = isParentChecked(d);
  });
    
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  const nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 0);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0);

  // Update the links…
  var link = container.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, d => d.target.id);

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .attr("opacity", "0.3")
    .style("stroke", 'black');

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

function findParent(datum) {
  if (datum.depth < 2) {
    return datum.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.parent)
  }
}

function findParentLinks(datum) {
  if (datum.target.depth < 2) {
    return datum.target.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.target.parent)
  }
}

const checkNode = (d, checked, byParent) => {
  d.checked = checked;
  const children = d.children || d._children;
  if (children)
    children.forEach(child => checkNode(child, checked, true));
    
  if (!byParent && checked && d.parent) {
    const siblings = d.parent.children || d.parent._children;
    const allChecked = siblings.every(s => s.checked);
    if (allChecked)
        checkNode(d.parent, true, false);
  }  
  
}

function isParentChecked (d) {
  if (!d.parent) {
    return false;
  }
  if (d.parent.checked) {
    return true;
  }
  return isParentChecked(d.parent);
}

function onClickCheckbox(d) {
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
  checkNode(d, d3.event.target.checked, false);
  console.log('ROOT: ', root);
  update(root);   
}


// Toggle children on click.
function onClickNode(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } 
  else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

const findNode = (parent, id) => {
  if (parent.id === id)
    return [parent];
    
  const children = parent.children || parent._children;
  if (children) {
        for (let child of children) {
        const found = findNode(child, id);
        if (found)
          return [...found, parent];
      }
  }
  return null;
}

const selectNode = id => {
   const node = findNode(treeData, id);
   if (node) {
      for (let index = node.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        expand(node[index]);
      }
      checkNode(node[0], true, false);
      update(root);
   }
};
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```